# How do I added a label to a Kubernetes pod when it has finished running it's startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have a pod that runs a script on startup. Once that script has finished executing I want to add a label to the pod so that it becomes available as part of a service. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a label, you can use a readiness probe. If a readiness probe is set on a pod, then that probe will be continuously executed to detect whether that pod is considered "ready" and therefore should become available as part of a service. If the probe returns false or error, the pod will not be put into service. Probes can hit an HTTP endpoint or run a script inside the container.

In your case, your script could drop a file somewhere to indicate that the pod is ready. A separate script in your container (specified in the readiness probe) could return true only if that file is present.

More information on readiness checks [can be found here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#liveness-and-readiness-probes-aka-health-checks).

(If you are still interested in adding a label to the pod, you can learn about [service accounts](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/) which allow pods to communicate with the apiserver.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's perfect! It's worth pointing out for anyone else trying to do this the examples are all about liveness, so to start I thought it wasn't working. But there is a separate `readinessProbe`.